# android mediacontroller - defining the mediacontroller in the layout xml

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In the android documentation on the MediaController widget I read

> Functions like show() and hide() have no effect when MediaController
>   is created in an xml layout.

which points to the fact the the mediacontroller can be defined in the xml layout. As I want a controller which never hides and also doesn't take the focus so that it is possible to click buttons on the rest of the screen I tried to go the xml layout way. As I can't get this to work I am looking for an example on how to use MediaController by defining it in the layout xml.

Any hint highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I found one workaround for Android 2.x. Sadly it doesn't seem to work in 4.x.

You need to call `setAnchorView()` to show the MediaController. This code worked for me in Android 2.2 and 2.3.6, but caused crash in 4.0.4:

```
mediaController.setAnchorView(mediaController);
```

I also tried passing activity content view to `setAnchorView()`, but it still crashing in 4.0.4.

The most reliable way is to instantiate it programatically as said in documentation:

> The way to use this class is to instantiate it programatically.