# android mediacontroller - how to catch events on the rest of the screen

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an Activity which shows details of an audio source. The user can edit the name of the audio etc. I also want to give the user the possibility to listen to the audio. For that I thought of showing the media controller at the bottom of the screen all the time (show(0))

My problem is now that the MediaController seems to take the focus and interaction with the rest of the screen is not possible anymore. Is there a way around this, showing the media controller but also allow interaction with the rest of the screen.

Any hint highly appreciated

**UPDATE**

found

[Android MediaController intercepts all other touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909603/android-mediacontroller-intercepts-all-other-touch-events)

my problem is that i cant get the idea of defining the mediacontroller in the xml to work, I have the same problems like Casebash was describing in his comments to the accepted solution.

I asked for an example for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875232/android-mediacontroller-defining-the-mediacontroller-in-the-layout-xml) your no answer yet.

Comment: the mediacontroller is not defined in the layout but programmatically - what i describe seems to be the intended behaviour yet i want to find a way around it ...